# Handle data exception while script execution in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on the dataset cleaning and processing the data for further analysis, I have used different cleaning scripts.

My script gets aborted whenever there is any unwanted exceptional data comes up in between the dataset , The script execution gets stuck and rest of the data doesn't gets processed.

**What I have been looking for :**

How I can process the whole dataset even if there is any exceptional/Unknown datatypes comes up in between the data by skipping and leaving the wrong datatypes as it is.

Any Exception handling technique i can use into this.

**Data frame I have been using :**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
```

Comment: Hi, it really depends on how you're doing this. Could you show more of you code?

Comment: @Laurent -  I have been performing the simple cleaning task with some columns, Whenever any new datatypes comes up, the script unable to handle it and gets stuck and don't process rest of the data

Answer (score 0):

Here is one general way to do that, which you can adapt to your specific tasks.

Let's say that you need to remove certain characters in a column, which contains strings **and** integers. This will raise an exception:

```py
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].replace('$', '')
```

So, you can do it like that:

```py
df["col_name"] = df["col_name"].apply(
    lambda x: x.replace("$", "") if isinstance(x, str) else x
)
```

I also want to mention that some pandas methods take an `errors` argument which can be set to `ignore`.

See for instance: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. just want to ask is there an way to handle Excel file like  error_bad_lines=False that we use in reading CSV file.

Comment: @Manz Sorry, I don't think so.